# Should the "last updated" field be initialized to something?

Tags: database, api, rest, date, timestamp

I'm building a REST API.

My users have `created_at` and `updated_at` fields.
These fields hold strings that look like this:

```
"2014-12-29T12:30:21+0000"
```

When I create a user, I set `created_at` to the current date.
However, I'm not sure if I should do the same for `updated_at`.
Technically, the user has never been updated.
But it seems weird for there not to be something there.

Should I leave the value `NULL`, make it the same as `created_at`, or do something else?

Comment: This depends on if your database or backing store requires updated_at to have a value. If it is an optional value then not setting it would probably be ok. Personally, I do my best to stay away from nullable fields when I can. If it was my code I would set updated_at to equal created_at...now both fields have a meaningful value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Creating is updating state (from nothing to something) so it can safely be considered an "update".

I would set the updated time on creation, if for no other reason than you don't have to cater for `null` values (ever).